# TinyMCE in MVC 5 application Greek charactes

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using TinyMCE Rich text Editor in my MVC app so to store data in a database. It works ok. The problem I have is that the data is in greek characters. It gives 
&kap&kap&kap&kap&kap&kap.

Can someone help me on how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
tinymce.init({
     entity_encoding : "raw"
});
```

[Documentation](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#entity_encoding)

[TinyMCE UTF-8 saving to MySQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20814377/tinymce-utf-8-saving-to-mysql-database)

Comment: thank you for your reply, It still gives me <p>&kappa;&alpha;&lambda;&eta;&mu;έ&rho;&alpha;</p> I put it at the head tag of create page

Comment: What content is inserting to databases? I don't now asp but your output is html or string? Look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653676/rendering-dynamic-html-content-into-variable-in-razor

Comment: for the now time I just insert some simple text. I manage to call my content  in a right format. I mean in my view page. But in db it still saves <p>&kappa;&alpha;&lambda;&eta;&mu;έ&rho;&alpha;</p> I use SQL Server

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "ArticleContent",
        entity_encoding : "raw"
    });
</script>